# New Activity not responding

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I have been trying to figure what's wrong on my own for 2 days now, but the second activity just won't start on button click, there are no error messages, no blank pages as if the button doesn't work, am I missing something obvious?

```
public class createMessage extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_message);
    }

    Button b ;

    public void clickSend(){
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(createMessage.this,receiveMessage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.typeMessage);
                String message = editText.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Second Activity:

```
public class receiveMessage extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_receive_message);


        // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(createMessage.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showMessage);
        textView.setText(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you are calling `clickSend` method ?

Answer (score 8):

You must call `clickSend()` method in `onCreate()` method.

Then only the `onClickListener` will work.

And remove calling the `startActivity(intent)` twice.

Change the code of `createMessage` class as below

```
public class createMessage extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_message);
        clickSend();
    }

    Button b ;

    public void clickSend(){
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(createMessage.this,receiveMessage.class);
                EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.typeMessage);
                String message = editText.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
     }
    }
```

Comment: Also include in your answer that OP doesn't need to call  `startActivity(intent);` twice.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `clickSend()` method inside your `onCreate()` method

**Edit:** Please check updated answer

```
public class createMessage extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
    Button b;
    EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_message);
        clickSend();
    }

    public void clickSend(){
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.typeMessage);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String message = editText.getText().toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(createMessage.this,receiveMessage.class);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Also include in your answer that OP doesn't need to call `startActivity(intent);` twice.

Answer (score 1):

Already existing answers will solve the problem but I think that you need to understand why your method was not called. Checking the docs for [activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), you'll see a bunch of listed methods and `onCreate` is one of them. Those methods are guaranteed to be called by the system for you (**never call one of that methods yourself**) and hence there is no need for you to call them. The problem is that the system doesn't know about your `clickSend` method and will never call it, letting that responsibility in your hands.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class createMessage extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
Button b ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_message);

    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(createMessage.this,receiveMessage.class);
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.typeMessage);
            String message = editText.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}  


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class createMessage extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
    Button b ;
    EditText editText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_message);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.typeMessage);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(createMessage.this,receiveMessage.class);
                String message = editText.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You should call `clickSend()` method from activity life-cycle method `onCreate()` to initialize the UI elements( like Button, EditText etc).

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_message);
   clickSend();
}
```

**2.** You are calling `startActivity()` twice. Update `clickSend()` method as below:

```
Button b ;
EditText editText;

public void clickSend(){
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.typeMessage);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(createMessage.this,receiveMessage.class);

            String message = editText.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```